# How can this Java code compile?

Tags: java, puzzle

A colleague came across some code that looked like this and couldn't understand how it could ever compile:

```
class FooClass {
  public static void bar(String arg) {
     System.out.println("arg = " + arg);
     http://www.google.com
     System.out.println("Done!");
  }
}
```

Basically, there was a random URL pasted in the middle of a method but `javac` didn't care.

We worked out so I'll post the answer if no-one else finds out but I thought it was interesting enough to post.

Comment: BTW, it works in C# (and probably C++) too.

Comment: Only one URL with each protocol is allowed, though (one "http", one "https", one "ftp", etc.). javac is kind of picky about that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"http:" is interpreted as a label.  What follows is an end-of-line comment.

Comment: break http; is just a secret identity of a GOTO statement they keep saying is EVIL and will not make a part of the language. I had no idea there were labels in Java... although I don't mean to say I consider GOTO and labels as evil as many others...

Answer (score 5):

You have a label

```
http:
```

followed by a comment

```
//www.google.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy. The highlighting on this site shows why.

http: is a label, as in break http;

//www.google.com is a comment.

Answer (score 2):

**http:** is the label.
**//** starts the comment.

Answer (score 2):

"http:" is a label, and the part after the "//" is, of course, a comment

Answer (score 1):

Another example with two http://

```
public class Main {
    {
        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program
        System.out.print("Hello ");
    } {
        http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html
        System.out.println("World!");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```