# Why hyperlink in Java source code does not produce compile error?

Tags: java

In the source code I forgot to add comment before the link.
For example, the following code:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    http://www.example.com/random-link-here
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

**Why it compiles?** Somehow unable to figure out what it does... Its like label for Goto + comment, but Java does not have a goto...

Comment: // is a comment

Comment: Are you **sure** you're compiling this code?

Comment: @nbro, try by yourself

Comment: Funny thing: even the auto-coloring on this site gives away that we have `label://comment` in there ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576468/why-does-a-http-url-in-java-compile

Comment: @Reimeus: Good find! I gave up after three pages, must not have used the right keywords.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `http:` part is a [label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) labelling the statement that follows. The `//` part introduces a [line comment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.7).

Normally you see labelled statements in directed `break` situations, like:

```
outer:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
         if (someConditionThatNeedsToTakeUsOutOfBothLoops) {
             break outer;
         }
    }
}
```

...however any statement may have a label. In your case you've labelled the `System.out.println("Hello World!");` statement.

Answer (score 5):

Because  :

```
http:   //www.example.com/random-link-here
^^^^    ^--------------------------------^
```

`http:` is a **label** and the rest is a **comment**

Comment: Label for what?

Answer (score 1):

This is a famous Java Puzzler. It is a label for a goto with a comment. Java reserves the goto keyword, but does not actually implement the goto statement. Look at Puzzler 22 from http://www.javapuzzlers.com/ as a related example.

Comment: "it doesn't work anymore"?

Comment: Java reserves the keyword `goto`, but Java has **never** actually had `goto`.

Comment: Ooh wow, I thought it did something in an earlier version. I'll edit my answer.